# NTPv4 Pool: Origin Timestamp is randomly filled in servers response - why?

Tags: linux, ntp

The NTPv4 server responses I get from pool.ntp.org servers (requested with chrony 3.5) have random filled values in the 64 origin timestamp field. I can't figure out why.

I can't find any information about this behavior in the corresponding [RFC 5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) reference document. My system clock is syncronized so this can not be an indication of an error.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

[The screenshot shows a Wireshark capture of the servers response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFmFT.png)

Comment: What does your client send in the 'Transmit timestamp' of the requests?

Comment: That is a good question: I just saw that the client is sending a random timestamp as well, so the servers response is as expected (the incoming time of the client request based on its transmit timestamp) but the client randomization is the weird thing. So my new question should be: Why is chrony producing random transmit timestamps in the client requests?

Comment: And for this question actually an answer exists: https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html It is a security feature, only provided by chrony. Thanks user1686 to pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Like [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) pointed out, the chrony client is producing the random transmit timestamp and the server is just answering this random timestamp in the origin field. This is a chrony specific security feature, documented [here](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html).